# Text at bottom of image for Firefox less 30

Tags: html, css, firefox, position

I have an image and at the bottom I want to display some text. If the text is more than one line the text should expand to the top.

```
<style>
    .image-wrapper td{
         position: relative;
    }

    .image-wrapper td div {
        bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        maring: 0 12px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .image-wrapper td div.left {
        text-align: left
    }

    .image-wrapper td div.right {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .image-wrapper td div.light {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .image-wrapper td div.dark {
        color: #ddd;
    }

</style>
<table class="image-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <img src="img/path/to/img.png">
        <div class="">Text at bottom</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Result looks like this:

- Chrome, IE 11, Firefox >= 30: [Correct Display Image](http://files.liebich.co/img_correct.png)
- Firefox < 30: [Wrong Display](http://files.liebich.co/img_wrong.png)

What do I have to change to make it also looking correctly for Firedox < 30?
Is it possible with CSS or do I have to use JavaScript?

Greetings
Sören

Comment: dont know what's "dic" in your css

Comment: That was a typing mistake. I correct it. dic should be a div. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You problem boils down to HTML/CSS not supporting positioning inside table cells.

Many modern browsers seem to have added support, but older browsers like IE (and perhaps Firefox < 30, not sure) just don't support it. You can try and wrap your div in another div, and give the wrapper a position of relative to set a positioning context, but again this only works sometimes. Here's an article on that hack: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/.

I'd suggest ditching your table and using div-based layout instead.